# JQuery DataTables server side pagination not working for data with 100+ entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to build a table that has the potential to have 100+ entries. When initializing the plugin I am setting the `bServerSide` attribute to `true` to use server side processing for pagination. In my JSON data for the table I am setting `iTotalRecords` equal to the total number of records before filtering, and `iTotalDisplayRecords` equal to the number of filtered records. In my case these two values are equal to one another.

For less than 100 records the pagination works as expected. However, with more than 100 entries several empty pages are created.

For example, here is a table with 108 entries and 20 entries on each page. Page 6 should be the last page of the table, but the links continue up to page 11 with no data on any of those pages.

[image]

Does anyone know what I could be missing? It seems very odd that the pagination works as expected for 99 records but not for 101.

My initialization code:

```
$table.dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-4'f><'col-sm-8'>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-8'p>>",
  "bDrawing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "bScrollCollapse": true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  "pageLength": 20,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bSortClasses": false,
  "sPageButton": "button",
  "aoColumns": aoColumns,
  "sAjaxSource": _typeSettings.getAllTagsUrl,
  "sAjaxDataProp": "bleTags.Tags",
});
```

A sample of my data as it would appear for 1 entry:

```
{  
   "bleTags":{  
      "Tags":[  
         {  
            "index":"0",
            "discoveryTime":{  
               "TimeStamp":"1507834225",
               "MilliSec":"733"
            },
            "iBeacon":{  
               "UUID":"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0",
               "major":"21845",
               "minor":"9029"
            },
            "packets":"2006",
            "RSSI":"-93",
            "battery":"0",
            "name":"",
            "lastPacket":{  
               "TimeStamp":"1507926755",
               "MilliSec":"693"
            },
            "manufacturer":"0x004C",
            "online":"false"
         }
      ]
   },
   "iTotalRecords":1,
   "iTotalDisplayRecords":1
}
```

A sample REST call:

```
http://localhost/restapi/ble/GetBLETags?sEcho=2&iColumns=10&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=40&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=function&mDataProp_2=function&mDataProp_3=function&mDataProp_4=function&mDataProp_5=function&mDataProp_6=function&mDataProp_7=function&mDataProp_8=function&mDataProp_9=9&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&sSearch_9=&bRegex_9=false&bSearchable_9=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=false&bSortable_1=false&bSortable_2=false&bSortable_3=false&bSortable_4=false&bSortable_5=false&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=false&bSortable_8=false&bSortable_9=false
```

Comment: I think your input data is just as relevant, could you post an example of that as well as your initialization code (reduced in some way if it's huge / has a lot of irrelevant code)

Comment: what is your   "pageLength" value ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera my pageLength value is 20

Comment: Ok, you need to show your server-side code too, since that is where your data is actually coming from - that may well be where the problem is.

Comment: @Mikk3lRo I've added my initialization code and a sample JSON response in my question above.

Comment: Is it conceivable that something goes wrong with the input when it reaches more than 100?

Comment: @Mikk3lRo not that I can tell. I may not be understanding the `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` properly though. Let's say that I have a set of 200 records, and I'm making a REST call that will return 20 of that set. Should `iTotalRecords` be set to 200 and `iTotalDisplayRecords` be set to 20?

Comment: `recordsFiltered` is the number of records in the table *after* searching / filtering. `recordsTotal` is the number of records the table would hold with *no* filter applied (ie all the records that *could* be shown in the table under any circumstance).

Comment: @Mikk3lRo I've added a sample REST call at the bottom of the initial question, and that is the one made when I fetch records 101-108 in my original example. Maybe you can spot something I missed. Thanks so much for looking at this, been fighting with it for days.

Comment: Is your pagination data getting returned from the REST call?

Comment: @Maantje Meaning the records themselves? If so yes, that's where I'm getting them.

Comment: Are you using some really old version of DataTables or using an old guide or something? Because I think the naming you use is from a legacy version.

Comment: @flemingslone Never mind got my libraries mixed up :|.

Comment: @Mikk3lRo I am using version 1.9.4, so if all else fails I'll try upgrading. I used this entry from Allen to clarify those parameters: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/512/clarification-of-itotalrecords-and-itotaldisplayrecords

Comment: Ok, I'd be very cautious following instructions from 2009. And I'm not going to set up tests for a 5 year old version. I'm not saying that is necessarily the problem. But update your code and see if that solves the problem first.

Comment: @Mikk3lRo thanks for your help. The creator of this plugin checks SO pretty regularly so I'm hoping he'll come along and have some idea.